# Pyparsing failed to parse multiple rules

Tags: python, pyparsing

I am trying to create Boolean query parser with some special rules like adjacent and near values. Rules i have created so far is

```
## DEFINITIONS OF SYMBOLS ###
NEAR = CaselessLiteral('near').suppress()
NUMBER = Word(nums)
NONEDIRECTIONAL = Combine(NEAR+NUMBER)
ADJ = CaselessLiteral("ADJ").setParseAction(replaceWith('0'))
OAND = CaselessLiteral("and")
OOR = CaselessLiteral("or")
ONOT = CaselessLiteral("not")

## ----------------------- ##
## DEFINITIONS OF TERMS ###
# Do not break quoted string.
QUOTED = quotedString.setParseAction(removeQuotes)

# space-separated words are easiest to define using just OneOrMore
# must use a negative lookahead for and/not/or operators, and this must come
# at the beginning of the expression
WORDWITHSPACE = OneOrMore(~(OAND | ONOT | OOR | NONEDIRECTIONAL | ADJ) +
                          Word(printables, excludeChars="()"))

# use a parse action to recombine words into a single string
WORDWITHSPACE.addParseAction(lambda t: ' '.join(t))

TERM = (QUOTED | WORDWITHSPACE)
## ----------------------- ##
## DEFINITIONS OF Expresion ###

EXPRESSION = infixNotation(TERM,
                           [
                               (ADJ, 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
                               (NONEDIRECTIONAL, 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
                               (ONOT, 1, opAssoc.RIGHT),
                               (Optional(OAND, default='and'), 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
                               (OOR, 2, opAssoc.LEFT)
                           ])
# As we can have more than one occurances of symbols together we are
# using `OneOrMore` Exprestions

BOOLQUERY = OneOrMore(EXPRESSION) + StringEnd()
## ----------------------- ##
```

When i run

> ((a or b) and (b and c)) or (a and d)

It works fine

Whereas when i try to parse

> ((((smart ADJ contract*) and agreement) or (enforced near3 without near3 interaction) or (automated ADJ escrow)) or ((protocol* or Consensus ADJ algorithm) near5 (agreement and transaction)))

It code stuck not able to process.

can any one help me out where i am going wrong ?

Updated code :

```
EXPRESSION = infixNotation(TERM,
                           [
                               (ONOT, 1, opAssoc.RIGHT),
                               (Optional(OAND, default='and'), 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
                               ((OOR | NONEDIRECTIONAL | ADJ), 2, opAssoc.LEFT)
                           ])
```

kept optional and because of cases like

> x not y not z

Comment: If "and" is optional, how will you determine if "a b" means the single term "a b" or the two separate terms "a" and "b" with an optional/implicit "and"? I think you will have to choose between implicit "and"-ing and unquoted multi-word terms, else your grammar is ambiguous.

Comment: How to create implicit grammar where i want one of "and/or/not" has to be there in the query?

Comment: Not sure I understood this question. To get rid of implicit 'and', remove `Optional` wrapper in `(Optional(OAND, default='and'), 2, opAssoc.LEFT),`, change to `(OAND, 2, opAssoc.LEFT),`

Comment: Ok Thank you FYI wiki space link is closed can you provide alternate link for documentation ?

Comment: The pyparsing docs are online at https://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/pyparsing-module.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is taking a long time because your `infixNotation` is 5 layers deep AND has an optional AND operator.

I was able to run this as-is by just enabling packrat parsing. Do this by adding to the top of your script (right after importing pyparsing):

```
ParserElement.enablePackrat()
```

To run your tests, I used `runTests`. It was not clear to me why BOOLQUERY was necessary, since you are just parsing expressions:

```
tests = """\
((a or b) and (b and c)) or (a and d)
((((smart ADJ contract*) and agreement) or (enforced near3 without near3 interaction) or (automated ADJ escrow)) or ((protocol* or Consensus ADJ algorithm) near5 (agreement and transaction)))
"""
EXPRESSION.runTests(tests)
```

Gives:

```
((a or b) and (b and c)) or (a and d)
[[[['a', 'or', 'b'], 'and', ['b', 'and', 'c']], 'or', ['a', 'and', 'd']]]
[0]:
  [[['a', 'or', 'b'], 'and', ['b', 'and', 'c']], 'or', ['a', 'and', 'd']]
  [0]:
    [['a', 'or', 'b'], 'and', ['b', 'and', 'c']]
    [0]:
      ['a', 'or', 'b']
    [1]:
      and
    [2]:
      ['b', 'and', 'c']
  [1]:
    or
  [2]:
    ['a', 'and', 'd']


((((smart ADJ contract*) and agreement) or (enforced near3 without near3 interaction) or (automated ADJ escrow)) or ((protocol* or Consensus ADJ algorithm) near5 (agreement and transaction)))
[[[[['smart', '0', 'contract*'], 'and', 'agreement'], 'or', ['enforced', '3', 'without', '3', 'interaction'], 'or', ['automated', '0', 'escrow']], 'or', [['protocol*', 'or', ['Consensus', '0', 'algorithm']], '5', ['agreement', 'and', 'transaction']]]]
[0]:
  [[[['smart', '0', 'contract*'], 'and', 'agreement'], 'or', ['enforced', '3', 'without', '3', 'interaction'], 'or', ['automated', '0', 'escrow']], 'or', [['protocol*', 'or', ['Consensus', '0', 'algorithm']], '5', ['agreement', 'and', 'transaction']]]
  [0]:
    [[['smart', '0', 'contract*'], 'and', 'agreement'], 'or', ['enforced', '3', 'without', '3', 'interaction'], 'or', ['automated', '0', 'escrow']]
    [0]:
      [['smart', '0', 'contract*'], 'and', 'agreement']
      [0]:
        ['smart', '0', 'contract*']
      [1]:
        and
      [2]:
        agreement
    [1]:
      or
    [2]:
      ['enforced', '3', 'without', '3', 'interaction']
    [3]:
      or
    [4]:
      ['automated', '0', 'escrow']
  [1]:
    or
  [2]:
    [['protocol*', 'or', ['Consensus', '0', 'algorithm']], '5', ['agreement', 'and', 'transaction']]
    [0]:
      ['protocol*', 'or', ['Consensus', '0', 'algorithm']]
      [0]:
        protocol*
      [1]:
        or
      [2]:
        ['Consensus', '0', 'algorithm']
    [1]:
      5
    [2]:
      ['agreement', 'and', 'transaction']
```